# How two join two tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, join

I'm a newbie in Oracle SQL, and I need help with the following:

Let's say I have a table with all the weeks of the year, for example:

```
ID_WEEK_YR
----------
2018011
2018012
2018013
...
2018124
```

And another table with the sales of a product only a certain weeks of the year

```
ID_PRODUCT    ID_WEEK_YR   SALES
----------    ----------  -------
TOY#1          2018083       5
TOY#1          2018051       3
TOY#1          2018043       1
```

I need to join the tables in order to obtain something like:

```
ID_PRODUCT    ID_WEEK_YR   SALES
----------    ----------  -------
TOY#1          2018011      null
TOY#1          2018012      null
TOY#1          2018013      null
...
TOY#1          2018043       5
...
TOY#1          2018051       1
...
TOY#1          2018083       3
...
TOY#1          2018124      null
```

Applying the typical JOIN possibilities from Oracle SQL, joining by the key ID_WEEK_YR, I obtain again the second table

```
SELECT 
    A11.ID_WEEK_YR,   
    A12.ID_PRODUCT
FROM 
    WEEKS_YR A11
    JOIN  SALES_U_YR A12
        ON (A11.ID_WEEK_YR=A12.ID_WEEK_YR)
WHERE a12.ID_PRODUCT='TOY#1';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with plsql, an imperative programming language. I will edit your post (and tags) to reflect that. The question is also unrelated to the specific user interface you are using, in your case PLSQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be close to the solution, you would just need to convert your (INNER) JOIN to a LEFT (OUTER) JOIN. Also all conditions on the left joined table have to be placed in the ON clause instead of the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
    'TOY#1',
    A11.ID_WEEK_YR,   
    A12.SALES
FROM 
    WEEKS_YR A11
    LEFT JOIN  SALES_U_YR A12
        ON A11.ID_WEEK_YR=A12.ID_WEEK_YR
        AND A12.ID_PRODUCT='TOY#1'
;
```